# Round nearest vs round up

Tags: bug, reputation

[image]

Reputation under 100 were rounded to the nearest 100 if your rep is over 10k. Now it seems to have been changed to rounding up. Is it an intentional change?

Comment: Writing something like “14.7k” is already a terrible nonconformity in itself. The additional wrong rounding bug probably doesn’t matter anymore at this point. :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that is probably caching, i.e. not a bug. Because now I see different values for your account depending on site within communities list:

On [MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/350567/%C9%AA%CA%99%E1%B4%9C%C9%A2):

> [image: mse]

On [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5958455/ibug):

> [image: so]

Another [user from SO](https://stackoverflow.com/users/472768/feifanz) reputation rounded to nearest:

> [image: so2]

Comment: No. I had never been over 14642 at the time I posted the question.

Comment: @ɪʙᴜɢ may be the rounding mode in the topbar menu differs from the communities list, but as you can see on the last image in the post - rounding made to the nearest (not to the up).

Comment: Confirmed it's caching issue. The number `14,642` is cached when it's actually 14,652 and rounded to 14.7k correctly.

Comment: [Another screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XZgYd.png)